# gitlab issues not work with Chinese

Tags: gitlab

When I create an issue, an enter Title and Details in Chinese.
But It not works.

> Form input
>   [image: form]
>
> Result

[image: submited]

Comment: Raise a bug on its issue tracker?

Comment: I wondered whether there exists any settings/configuration that can get ride of this.

Comment: Anyway , I raised a issue.  https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation "Setup Database"](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/databases.md) does mention

```
# Create the GitLab production database
mysql> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `gitlabhq_production` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`;
```

So it could be possible this charset is missing in your database.

[Johannes Schleifenbaum](https://github.com/jojosch) [mentions](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4620#issuecomment-21396140) in [your issue 4620](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4620):

> Are your database and tables (in this case issues) created with utf8 character-set/collation? I had the exact same issue.

```
$: mysql -ugitlab -p gitlabhq_production
mysql> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM issues;
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "character_set_database";
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "collation_database";
```

The blog post "[Converting Character sets in MySQL to UTF8](http://zee.balogh.sk/?p=928)" proposes different options, including:

```
mysql> ALTER DATABASE gitlabhq_production DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
mysql> ALTER TABLE issues CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;,
```

Comment: @jilen could you try a `mysql> ALTER DATABASE gitlabhq_production DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;` and `mysql> ALTER TABLE issues CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`, and then try and create a new issue in your GitLab? More info at http://zee.balogh.sk/?p=928

Comment: Then I should alter every table into utf8. That's really a pain.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. Now everything is ok.